# Disable Wordpress welcome message when i create a user

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

I have a Wordpress multisite installation and I want to create users without sending them automatically an email with their login credentials or any other email.

I tried a lot of plugins but they don't not work. Is there any way to disable this manually in like functions.php file?

I already disabled two messages with the filters below:

```
add_filter( 'wpmu_welcome_notification', '__return_false' ); 
add_filter( 'wpmu_welcome_user_notification', '__return_false' );
```

But the user still gets one email when I create it:

> Dear User, Your new account has been set up.
>
> You can log in with the following information: Username: xxxxxxx
>   Password: xxxxxxx
>
> http://site.example.com/wp-admin/
>
> Thanks!

I tried disabling all other plugins.

Comment: Well 4.3 got rid of passwords in emails, just an FYI. Now it will ask them to set their password.

Comment: I know that. I use a plugin to show me the password field and let me choose the password.

Comment: Did you disable that specific plugin too?

Comment: All plugins. That too.